# Chrome - Javascript sorting inconsistently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sorting

I'm aware of Chrome's unstable sorting issues, but I'm at a loss on how to address this when sorting strings.

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b){
        var typeA=a.toLowerCase();
        var typeB=b.toLowerCase();

        return (typeA < typeB) ? -1 : (typeA > typeB) ? 1 : 0;
        });
```

works fine in FF and Safari, but in Chrome this still returns an incorrect order. That is, Chrome doesn't honor that if typeA == typeB, return 0...it still chooses to move it. Is there a fix out there for dealing with sorting strings?

Comment: You could "fix" this by implementing your own sort algo instead of using `array.sort()`. But I am not sure if there might be a way to get `array.sort()` to work on its own.

Comment: What is the contents of `myArray`?

Comment: Just as a coding comment:  Don't get me wrong, I love the ternary operator `?` but I agree with those who believe it should never be tested.  Real life isn't code golf, don't afraid to split that into an `if ... else if ... else` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS spec doesn't require sorting algorithm to be stable, so you can't count on that.

The only definite ways to solve unstable sorting issue is to either manually code different, stable algorithm or to add one additional unique key to sort on to guarantee that comparison function would always treat two elements as either greater or lesser to each other, but never as equal. Original array index would do.